# android unable to parse a single json element

Tags: android, json, parsing

Hi I am unable to parse a single json element from the Json output from my PHP.
My Json output look Like this.

```
 {"success":1,"question":[{"question":"Question2"}]}
```

My code is

```
try {
    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

    if (success == 1) 
    {
        Questions = json.getJSONArray(TAG_Questions);
        Log.d("users_list.length() : ", String.valueOf( Questions.length())); 

        for (int i = 0; i <  Questions.length(); i++) 
        {
            JSONObject c = Questions.getJSONObject(i);          
            Quensstring[i] =  c.getString("question" + i);
            System.out.println("Exception : " + Quensstring[i]);
        } 
    } else {
        // no products found
        // Launch Add New product Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), day1q1.class);
        // Closing all previous activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return null;


protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) 
{   
    dialog.dismiss();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {   
            System.out.println("usersMap.get(User1) : " + Quensstring[0]);  
            Question.setText(Quensstring[0]);   
        }
    });
```

Please help me I could not find the error.
Here is My logcat

```
09-13 05:46:08.459: D/All :(1353): {"success":1,"question":[{"question":"Question2"}]}
09-13 05:46:08.459: D/users_list.length() :(1353): 1
09-13 05:46:08.499: W/System.err(1353): org.json.JSONException: No value for question0
09-13 05:46:08.499: W/System.err(1353):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
09-13 05:46:08.539: W/System.err(1353):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
09-13 05:46:08.589: W/System.err(1353):     at com.example.newairways.day1q1$Question.doInBackground(day1q1.java:474)
09-13 05:46:08.589: W/System.err(1353):     at com.example.newairways.day1q1$Question.doInBackground(day1q1.java:1)
09-13 05:46:08.589: W/System.err(1353):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
09-13 05:46:08.589: W/System.err(1353):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-13 05:46:08.589: W/System.err(1353):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-13 05:46:08.589: W/System.err(1353):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
09-13 05:46:08.599: W/System.err(1353):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
09-13 05:46:08.599: W/System.err(1353):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
09-13 05:46:08.626: W/System.err(1353):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-13 05:46:08.649: I/System.out(1353): usersMap.get(User1) : null
```

Comment: `c.getString("question" + i);` this is the culprit. You don't have json object with key as question0, question1, etc

Comment: I formatted your code but you are missing some of your first method, please edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{"success":1,"question":[**{"question":"Question2"}**]}. Your JSONArray has only one JSONObject and that JSONObject has only 1 tag which is **"question"**. So replace your code

```
Quensstring[i] =  c.getString("question" + i);
```

with

```
String quensString =  c.getString("question");
```

Hopes this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following line:

```
 Quensstring[i] =  c.getString("question" + i);
```

With:

```
 Quensstring[i] =  c.getString("question");
```

As the json string tag is only `question`